# Probability of flipping at least 2 heads when flipping a coin 100 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I tried using finding the contrary, that is the probability of getting 1 (100C1/2^100) heads and then 0 heads (100C0/2^100) and using the formula that P = 1 - P(b), where P(b) is the probability of the opposite. But when. I do P = 1 - ((100C1/2^100) + (100C0/2^100)), I get 1... which doesn't make any sense. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Well, it's basically $1$, surely.  $\binom {100}0=1,\binom {100}1=100$ so you are subtracting $\frac {101}{2^{100}}$ which is very close to $0$.

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong except relying on technology too much.  Calculators have limited precision and will incorrectly think that two numbers that are "close enough" but technically different are in fact the same, as is the case here.

Comment: You have the right idea, but it is so highly probable that it is very nearly 1, and you have lost information due to rounding.

Comment: Whenever a calculation for $1-f(x)$ evaluates to $1$, look at the calculation for $f(x)$ .

Answer (score 5):

The calculation of getting at least $2$ is  $$1-C^{100}_1\frac{1}{2^{100}} - C^{100}_0\frac{1}{2^{100}} = 1-\frac{101}{2^{100}}$$ but this is very close to $1$ and is in fact $$\frac{1267650600228229401496703205275}{1267650600228229401496703205376} \approx 0.999999999999999999999999999920325$$ which your calculator rounded to $1$

What this is saying is that you are extremely likely to get at least $2$ heads when flipping a coin $100$ times